# Add keyframes to the geometry nodes modifier input values using python

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I am trying to animate scene using Blender Python to change values of the Geometry Nodes modifier inputs, but I get an error saying `TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "Input_2" not found`.

For the `keyframe_insert()` I've used same logic as I found it for standard modifiers.

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2"] = 2
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"].keyframe_insert(data_path="Input_2",frame=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution was to use the string for `data_path` as `'["Input_2"]'`